# Processing audio output from AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Quite simple question:

- I have an AVPlayer playing a video taken from my iphone/ipad library using UIImagePickerController.
- I would like to apply various audio processing on the audio output from the video player, such as filters & convolutions.

What's the best way to do this (i.e. which framework/class)?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with AVPlayer. It's been several years since I've messed with this, but I seem to remember that you want to use AVFoundation to create a media capture session. You'd feed the video input from your source recoding into a recording output stream, but run the audio from the audio channel of your recording, through your filter, and to the recording. (For batch processing rather than realtime at least.) See the AFFoundation docs in Xcode - specifically the section titled "Cameras and Media Capture"

Comment: (And no, it's not simple. I find those lower-level frameworks hard to figure out.)

Comment: Thanks Duncan, that helps! (the question seemed though). Still, this post seems to discuss around it - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/90879
I'll explore both ways...

Comment: Years ago there was a demo app from Apple called ChromaKey that showed how to filter out the green in a video stream. It used the approach I outlined. It was written in Objective-C, and probably targeted iOS 6 or 7, to give you an idea of how old it was. The big trick it illustrated was how to map pixel buffers from Core Video into OpenGL and out again without having to copy memory. That enabled me to pass the video stream through OpenGL and apply texture mapping to it, at the full video frame rate.

Comment: Indeed, MTAudioProcessingTap sounds like it might be what you want. I found this: https://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/

Comment: Nice insight. I was also reading that post ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way was to separate audio from video, and apply audio processing on the audio using AVAudioEngine, while synchronizing both players.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

extension CGRect {
    init(_ x:CGFloat, _ y:CGFloat, _ w:CGFloat, _ h:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x, y:y, width:w, height:h)}
}
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
    var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    var f = AVAudioFile()
    var player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    var effect = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 4)
    var timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    var didInitialLayout = false
    var videoplayer = AVPlayer()
    var videostate = 0
    var freq = [150, 250, 3000, 6000]

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            return .all
        }
        return .landscape
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode:.default)
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }


    @IBAction func launchVideoPlayer(_ sender: Any) {
        self.videoplayer.pause()
        let urlvideo = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"videofile",     withExtension:"mp4")!
        self.videoplayer = AVPlayer(url:urlvideo)
        let av = AVPlayerViewController()
        av.showsPlaybackControls = false
        av.player = videoplayer
        av.view.frame = CGRect(140,20,1100,800)
        self.addChild(av)
        self.view.addSubview(av.view)
        av.didMove(toParent:self)
        self.videostate = 1
    }

    @IBAction func audioprocess(_ sender: Any) {
        self.engine.stop()
        self.engine = AVAudioEngine()
        self.player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"yoursong", withExtension: "m4a")!
        self.f = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
        self.engine.attach(player)
        self.effect = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 4)
        let bands = effect.bands
        for i in 0...(bands.count - 1) {
            bands[i].frequency = Float(self.freq[i])
        }
        bands[0].gain = 10.0
        bands[0].filterType = .parametric
        bands[0].bandwidth = 1
        bands[1].gain = 10.0
        bands[1].filterType = .parametric
        bands[1].bandwidth = 0.5
        bands[2].gain = 0.0
        bands[2].filterType = .parametric
        bands[2].bandwidth = 1
        bands[3].gain = 0.0
        bands[3].filterType = .parametric
        bands[3].bandwidth = 1
        self.engine.attach(effect)
        self.engine.connect(player, to: effect, format: f.processingFormat)
        let mixer = self.engine.mainMixerNode
        self.engine.connect(effect, to: mixer, format: f.processingFormat)
        player.scheduleFile(f, at: nil) {
            print("stopping")
            delay(0.1) {
                if self.engine.isRunning {
                    print("engine was running, really stopping")
                    self.engine.stop()
                }
            }
        }
        self.engine.prepare()
        try! self.engine.start()
        player.play()
    
        if self.videostate == 1 {
            self.videoplayer.play()
        } else {
            return }
    }

    @IBAction func stopsound(_ sender: Any) {
        self.player.stop()
        self.videoplayer.pause()
    }
    
    @IBAction func changeEQ(_ sender: Any) {
        let bands = self.effect.bands
        for i in 0...(bands.count - 1) {
            bands[i].frequency = Float(self.freq[i])
        }
        bands[0].bypass = false
        bands[1].bypass = false
        bands[2].bypass = false
        bands[3].bypass = false
        bands[0].gain = -60.0
        bands[0].filterType = .parametric
        bands[0].bandwidth = 1
        bands[1].gain = -40.0
        bands[1].filterType = .parametric
        bands[1].bandwidth = 0.5
        bands[2].gain = -20.0
        bands[2].filterType = .parametric
        bands[2].bandwidth = 1
        bands[3].gain = 0.0
        bands[3].filterType = .parametric
        bands[3].bandwidth = 1
        self.engine.attach(effect)
    }
}
```